# How can I ensure that correct function is called in case there are multiple candidates

Tags: c++

In C++ is perfectly legitimate to do:

```
bool x = "hi";
```

Because "hi" is translated by compiler to a char array and returns a pointer to that array, which is a number and number can be implicitly converted to `bool` (0 is false, anything else is true).

So I have these ctor:

```
Exception(QString Text, bool __IsRecoverable = true);
Exception(QString Text, QString _Source, bool __IsRecoverable = true);
```

Sadly I figured out that calling

```
Exception *e = new Exception("error happened", "main.cpp @test");
```

It creates a new instance of "Exception" class which is created using `Exception(QString Text, bool __IsRecoverable = true);` constructor, which is wrong to a point.

Is there a simple way to ensure that correct function is called, other than restructuring the constructors entirely, changing position of arguments, etc?

Comment: reworded :P to legitimate

Comment: @JosephMansfield Well I use this conversion frequently to add extra test to my `assert`s. but assigning to a `bool` like this looks fishy, i agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not sure why you're dynamically allocating an exception class. I'm not sure that's ever a good idea.

You can explicitly construct a `QString`:

```
Exception e("error happened", QString("main.cpp @test"));
```

Or you can pass the third argument:

```
Exception e("error happened", "main.cpp @test", true);
```

Or you can add an additional constructor that takes `const char*` and will be preferred over the conversion to `bool`:

```
Exception(QString Text, const char* Source, bool IsRecoverable = true);
```

You can easily make this forward to the `QString` version. Also note that names beginning with an underscore and a capital letter or with two underscores are reserved.

Comment: I am dynamically allocating it here in this example, of course in my code I do `throw SomeNS::Exception("blabla", "other blabla");` I am aware it's a bad practice as I would need to clean up the memory in catch block

Comment: @awesomeyi Yes, that's my preferred option too. One of the few cases where I don't mind seeing a C-style string type.

Comment: Also in code you add (almost) always use the explicit keyword for cast operators and Ctors.. Avoids adding to the mess

Comment: I did know that underscode + capital are reserved, I didn't know that applies for double underscore though. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: @Petr A double underscore anywhere in a name is reserved.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to not use default arguments. They contribute to overload resolution problems like this, and anyway it is not very readable to just see `true` as an argument. Whoever's reading the code then has to stop and go look up what the `true` means. Even if it's yourself you may forget it in a few months time when you come back to the code, especially if you do this sort of thing a lot.

For example:

```
struct Exception: public whatever
{
    Exception(char const *text);
    Exception(char const *text, char const *source);
};

struct RecoverableException: public Exception
{
    RecoverableException(char const *text);
    RecoverableException(char const *text, char const *source);
};
```

It's a little bit more typing in this source file but the payoff is that your code which actually uses the exceptions is simpler and clearer.

To implement these constructors you could have them all call a particular function in the .cpp file with relevant arguments selecting which behaviour you want.

I have a preference for using `char const *` rather than `QString` as I am paranoid about two things:

- unwanted conversions
- memory allocation failure

If constructing a QString throws then things go downhill fast.   But you may choose to not worry about this possibility because if the system ran out of memory and your exception handling doesn't prepare for that possibility then it's going to terminate either way.